# Running Timer in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, datagridview

I'm using LINQ to populate objects from a SQL database into a DataGridView. I have one column that needs to have a constantly running stopwatch to display the time since the entry was added, however, many clients will be pulling from this database and I would prefer not to query the database constantly just to retrieve a value I can already calculate. For example, this is what the DGV looks like:

[image]

Since I already queried "Start DateTime", there should be a way to simply increment the "Duration" fields via a timer without having to move all that unnecessary data across the network over and over.

Is there a way to handle a single column programmatically while linking the DataSource to a database for the other columns?

---

**Update [5/28/14 5:23 PM CT]:**

If it helps, here is the code to bind the DataSource ("Duration" is unbound):

```
private void IncidentsModule_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    incidentList.DataSource = model.GetOngoingIncidents().Select(i => new { 
            Name = i.Name, 
            SHDTicket = i.SHDTicket, 
            StartDateTime = i.StartDateTime 
        }).ToList();
}
```

And here is the current code for the timer based on input from **TaW**:

```
private void incidentDurationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in incidentList.Rows)
    {
        dr[IncidentDurationColumn.Index] = DateTime.Now.Second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can add unbound columns to data-bound `DataGridViews`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkatshfa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @adv12 Ahh, that makes sense. But how do I update the "Duration" column without the grid repopulating the other columns? Right now it is refreshing everything and also causing the selection to repeatedly move to the 0 index row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Timer `duractionTimer` with Interval=1000.

Let `dataTable` be the Table the DataGridView is bound to.

Let `durationcolumnIndex` be the index of the duration column

Replace `DateTime.Now.Second` with the value you calculate for each row!

```
private void duractionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        dr[durationcolumnIndex] = DateTime.Now.Second;
    }
}
```

This will automatically set the column, even if it is bound. Make sure to

- Not write it back
- At larger intervals re-retrieving the data from the server to stay in synch

**Edit:**

When I wrote the answer I didn't realize that LINQ does not return a regular ADO DataSet/DataTable. Instead the DataSource will contain a `IQueryable<Table>`.

Assuming the table LINQ accesses is named *IncidentTable* You can access the *Duration* column of each row in the `timer_Tick` event :

```
foreach (var vv in  incidentList.DataSource as IQueryable<IncidentTable>)
{
   vv.Duration = // your computed value here
}
```

Note: This assumes that the Duration column is **still bound**. If you have unbound it, you can got through the DGV-Rows-Cells directly without the special magic of accessing the resultset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think it will solve my problem but I am having trouble retrieving the DataTable for the DGV. Also, it seems to want "DataGridViewRow" rather than "DataRow". I've tried many variations but continue to receive runtime errors relating to invalid casts. Updated question with my code. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to change the values in the `DataTable`; if incidentList is the `DataGridView` then the `DataTable` should be `incidentList.DataSource.Tables[0]`. If you have problems with that, try to stop the Debugger at a line where the DGV is filled and in scope and have a look at it; drilling into it, you should be able to see its `DataSource` and its `DataTable`..

Comment: I was wrong - You won't find a `DataTable` in the `DataSource`, you won't even find a `DataSet` in the `DataSource`, just the tablerows as an IQueryable List. See my edited answer!